# EntityFramework - How to populate child members?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have been given a model to work with but cannot figure out the LINQ query to get what I need into my object.

Given an initial date, I need to retrieve all of the items posted for sale since then, member details, and the filenames of the photos of those items.
Also need to be able to pass in a MemberID and find which items they have for sale (and filenames)
[image: EF Model]
Can someone please point me to what the query for this would be?
I've been following a few EF tutorials but am having lots of trouble figuring this one out...

When I try this, I get a null reference exception when talking to the photoURL.

```
var items = db.BuySellLists.Include(b => b.Member)
                        .Include(b => b.BuySellPhoto)
                        .Where(b => b.PostedDate >= fromDate && b.IsBuyable == true)
                        .OrderBy(b => b.PostedDate)
                        .ToList();
```

I've currently got it working by looking up all items for sale, then from there looping over each BuySellListId to get that items photos to get the URL, but this causes quite a few individual queries to the database and is giving performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photo is not implicitly included in your query. That is why you get a NullReferenceException. You need to include it explicitly as follows:

```
Include(b => b.BuySellPhoto.Photo)
```

Check [MSDN documentation on Include extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!
Turns out that was just one piece of the puzzle. The PostedDate on some of the Items was dated last year, and noone had actually entered any photo data... Feeling pretty silly for that part.